# Convert Object[][] to String? Java Swing

Tags: java, string, swing, object, jtextarea

I need to convert an Object[][] that looks like this:

```
Object[][] numbers =
  {"1", "12-22", "12-22"},
  {"2", "12-22", "11-14"},
  {"3", "12-22", "11-14"};
```

I tried:

```
m1.textArea.setText((b1.returnNumbers).toString());
```

Comment: What should the resultant string look like? There's no "built-in" way to do this because I don't think there's a way to do so that will be correct in almost all cases. Your best bet is to construct your own string with two loops and a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Use a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for this type of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method:

```
m1.textArea.setText(Arrays.deepToString(b1.returnNumbers));
```

Comment: It's almost working! The problem is the only thing that shows up is ''null''. But, thank you!

Comment: @Cereal101 You are welcome! Once you overcome the `null` problem, you may want to comment on what has caused it. Then, when your problem is solved, you may want to accept an answer to let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and to earn a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Will do! I guess you noticed I'm new here?